# Wordpress create custom pages with permalinks from custom table data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, permalinks

I have 1 custom table (not wp core table) where are specific products imported. I've set up custom wp page where these products are listed, custom filter created etc. In this step so far everything is OK - products are listed and filtering works, pagination works...

But what I want to extend further now - open each product page (like /product-listing-page/product-name-1) when clicking on product names in product list page... How can be this achieved "out of wp_posts" table?

Why I'm not using wp_posts table: web site have static pages and dynamic posts as news and product table is truncated and re-imported once in a day every night! So, can not really use wp_posts page when product list is dynamic and totally truncated before each import...

Any ideas? Maybe anybody already did such stuff?;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was quite quick and easy! For my needs it was enough just to         register global query var:

```
    function register_new_query_var($vars) {
        $vars[] = 'product_id';
        return $vars;

    add_filter('query_vars', 'register_new_query_var');
```

and then I changed theme template for page product-listing-page to work for product listing and individual products with using 
if(!get_query_var('product_id')). So, if query empty - do listing stuff, if not empty - do individual product stuff!

For me this is quite enough and I do not need even seo friendly urls (because product list changes every day, so - every day will be new products, links, and there will be to much 404 errors)...

and I can use http://example.com/product-listing-page?product_id=1 and page displays with date which is from custom table! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you developed a plugin to handle all the custom table and code you created, but if you didn't, I strongly encourage you to do so.

Because by making your code as a plugin, you have the oportunity to use all the composants of wordpress, like the rewrite rules system, which, I think, could help you to achieve your goal.

I created a plugin some times ago for a website I have the charge and I needed a custom page to be displayed within the website (worpdress) url system, which is what you want to do if I correctly understand your question.
Unfortunately the plugin has evolved since and I didn't keep a backup of that code, but if I remember correctly how I did it back when, here is the rough approach I followed:

I create a plugin which handle :

- custom db table(s)
- custom php objects
- ...

AND (this is the intersting part) add rewrite rule to wordpress rewrite rules system as follow:

1. set rewrite tag (init action) (if needed)
2. add rewrite rule (init action)
3. intercept url and parse it to get the params i need in my custom
   page (parse_request action)

The following functions may help you with that :

- [add_rewrite_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/)
- [add_rewrite_rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)

And you need to hook in :

- [init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/)
- [parse_request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/)

Hope it helps you start.